# What temporal formula to use for knapsack problem?

Tags: visual-studio-code, knapsack-problem, tla+, pluscal

In "Practical TLA+" by Hillel Wayne, Chapter 3 goes over [an implementation of the Knapsack Problem in PlusCal](https://github.com/Apress/practical-tla-plus/blob/master/Chapter%203/knapsack.tla).

Although I understand the implementation, I don't understand how to run it. He mentions:

> Since we’re adding a PlusCal spec, remember to remove “evaluate constant
> expression” and set “What is the behavior spec?” to “Temporal formula.” When you run
> this, you should get something like what is shown in Figure 3-3.
>
> [image: figure 3-3 the error]

What's the "Temporal Formula"? Where is it in the Model menu? Alternatively, how would I run this using the [VSCode TLA+ plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alygin.vscode-tlaplus)? I feel like I missed some details I need to actually run/verify this specification.

Answer (score 0):

It's under "model overview > what is the behavior spec".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

TLA+ specifications can specify different things, not only iterative algorithms. The `knapsack.tla` that you have linked specifies the problem and the definition of an optimal solution without describing a good way to really find it with a computer.

```
ValidKnapsacks(itemset) ==
  {sack \in [Items -> 0..4]: KnapsackSize(sack, itemset) <= Capacity}
```

`[Items -> 0..4]` is the set of all possible mappings from `Item` to the sizes `0..4`. The optimal solution is in the subset that fits in a knapsack of size `Capacity`, hence the expression `KnapsackSize(sack, itemset) <= Capacity`.

Another TLA+ definition defines which one of the knapsacks is the best of them all in an impressively high-level way:

```
BestKnapsack(itemset) ==
  LET all == ValidKnapsacks(itemset)
  IN CHOOSE best \in all:
    \A worse \in all \ {best}:
      KnapsackValue(best, itemset) > KnapsackValue(worse, itemset)
```

It basically says: among all of the valid knapsacks, the best knapsack is the one that is better (higher `KnapsackValue`) than all others.

What you are looking for is an specification of an iterative algorithm that matches this solution specification. The specification of the algorithm will have `Init` and `Next` formulas and then you can check that it eventually terminates — usually called `Termination` — and the state variable storing the knapsack would then contain the `BestKnapsack`.

But you can "run" these definitions by typing an expression in the "Evaluate Constant Expression" box.

[image: evaluating constant expressions]

The author also wrote two refined definitions of `BestKnapsack` — `BestKnapsackOne` and `BestKnapsackTwo`. They are still functional and we call them refined because they are getting closer to something implementable in an iterative algorithm.

You can evaluate them just like done above for `BestKnapsack(HardcodedItemSet)`. They are correct refinements if they match the output of `BestKnapsack` for all possible inputs. Since this is model checking, "all possible inputs" is qualified with "up to a certain size" and we assume (or prove) that the solution extends to any size.